# How do I extend/override \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu::_getMenuItemClasses?

Tags: magento2, overrides, plugin

I cannot find it di.xml. Any ideas?

I want to add a custom css class to specific TopMenu items. I don't know how to extend this.

Comment: Since it is a 'protected' method, you need to use a rewrite/preference.

Comment: I did, but the menu isn't rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For overriding the topmenu class you can preference.

### step1

Add di.xml in Shahroz/Menu/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config>
    <preference for="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" type="Shahroz\Menu\Block\Html\Topmenu" />
</config>
```

### step2

create custom class Shahroz\Menu\Block\Html\Topmenu.php

```
<?php

namespace Shahroz\Menu\Block\Html;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\Node;
use Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu as MagentoTopmenu;

class Topmenu extends  MagentoTopmenu
{

    /**
     * Returns array of menu item's classes
     *
     * @param Node $item
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getMenuItemClasses(Node $item)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/topmenu.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('text message');
        $classes = [
            'level' . $item->getLevel(),
            $item->getPositionClass(),
        ];

        if ($item->getIsCategory()) {
            $classes[] = 'category-item';
        }

        if ($item->getIsFirst()) {
            $classes[] = 'first';
        }

        if ($item->getIsActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'active';
        } elseif ($item->getHasActive()) {
            $classes[] = 'has-active';
        }

        if ($item->getIsLast()) {
            $classes[] = 'last';
        }

        if ($item->getClass()) {
            $classes[] = $item->getClass();
        }

        if ($item->hasChildren()) {
            $classes[] = 'parent';
        }

        return $classes;
    }
}
```

### Step3

Now you can check var/log there will be new log file topmenu.log.If the file is there its means your are successful.